# USB-HID data initialisation

Tags: java, linux, triggers, usb, hid

I configured the USB driver at my RPi4 as a USB-Slave device and set the USB descriptors in the RPI4 to enumarate as a ordenary USB keyboard.
Therefore I wrote a Java program on the RPi4 which read-in the keyboard states from the USB driver (Scroll-Lock, Num-Lock, and so on)

This works great. I can plug in the RPi4 at any PC. If I hit the Num-Lock key at the hardware- keyboard my RPi recognizes the change at the same time and shows the same state in the Java programm as the led at the hardware keyboard.

But how the heck does initialisation work for such states? I did not find any hint at the USB documentation upto now.

- When Num-Lock on the PC is "on" (true) and I plug in the RPi the state in
  my Java program stays "false". (incorrect)
- At the moment I hit the
  Num-Lock key (PC change to false), my programm gets the update and
  shows "false", too. (correct)
- At the moment I hit the Num-Lock key again (PC change to true), my programm gets the update and shows "true", too. (correct)

This event-triggered data flow from PC to RPI4 works as intended and is absolutely right.
But how can I trigger in this USB data flow model a "manual update" for my program internal states at the startup of my Java program?

Answer (score 0):

To detect the state of the numlock/capslock/scrolllock you need to read the values of the respective LED lights report that the host sends to the device soon after it is plugged in.

Comment: Thats what my USB Lib does. At the start of my Java program the Lib start a reading thread. The thread waits for a change in the input report block driver file. Thats the reason my program reacts correctly to state changes. But this block file seems not to hold a "initial-change" for the thread for a initial read. I can only detect reports which arrive after my program is launched.